# deep copy json simplied

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, deep-copy

Trying to copy a json object but when there is a string in it I need only few key/value pairs from it and have it copied to another json object (simplified);
Data in JSON is something like this

```
{ __createdAt: "2018-07-30T08:19:32.523Z",
  orderid: '12345',
  refund: null,
  order_verified: null,
  in_process: null,
  location_id: null,
  userInfo: '{"countrySelect":"DE","postalCode":"64289","ShippingCountry":"Germany","City":"Darmstadt","GooglePlace":"Darmstadt Germany","ShippingRegion":"Hesse","CustomerEmail":"myemail@gmail.com"}',
  payment: null,
  shippingInfo: 1437,
  taxInfo: 0,
  orderTotal: 5712,
  order_weight: 0,
  order_notes: '' }
```

The result I am trying to achieve after copying is something like this.

```
{ __createdAt: "2018-07-30T08:19:32.523Z",
  orderid: '12345',
  refund: null,
  order_verified: null,
  in_process: null,
  location_id: null,
  countrySelect:"DE",
  ShippingCountry:"Germany",
  City:"Darmstadt",
  CustomerEmail:"myemail@gmail.com",
  payment: null,
  shippingInfo: 1437,
  taxInfo: 0,
  orderTotal: 5712,
  order_weight: 0,
  order_notes: '' }
```

I dont know what data would come from the DB, but whenever it contains string I could hardcode it to get specific values from string within a json. 
Tried deep copy, but couldn't get this done correctly. Its not that I haven't tried getting this done but couldn't come up a way to make it more generic instead of hardcoded. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to give a little more context, is the JSON string o my ever 1 level deep?

Comment: yes. there could be multiple JSON strings but it'll be one level deep.

Comment: Is it always the `userInfo` property that contains the JSON?

Comment: No, but there are no more than 2 or 3. This is the part where it has to be little hardcoded.

Comment: if "userInfo" comes up we copy  2 3 key/values from it which are pre defined.

Comment: Doable, but it sounds like an X/Y problem. Better to fix the backend rather than to search each string value for a possible JSON string to parse

Comment: data is being pulled from DB like this. can't do anything about it. can you please guide me into the direction how it is doable ? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say it will only ever be one level deep, you don't really need a "deep" copy so to speak. It sounds as if you only need to test strings to see if they are `JSON.parse`able, and if so to include their key/value pairs in the object.

If that's the case, a simple try/catch will do the trick. You could also add another check after the `JSON.parse` to verify that the output of the parse is in fact an object, or to filter out certain key values, etc.

```js
const src = {
  __createdAt: "2018-07-30T08:19:32.523Z", orderid: '12345', refund: null, order_verified: null, in_process: null, location_id: null,
  userInfo: '{"countrySelect":"DE","postalCode":"64289","ShippingCountry":"Germany","City":"Darmstadt","GooglePlace":"Darmstadt Germany","ShippingRegion":"Hesse","CustomerEmail":"myemail@gmail.com"}',
  payment: null, shippingInfo: 1437, taxInfo: 0, orderTotal: 5712, order_weight: 0, order_notes: ''
}

function copyExpand(target, source) {
  for (let k in source) {
    if (typeof source[k] === 'string') {
      try {
        let json = JSON.parse(source[k]);
        copyExpand(target, json);
      } catch (e) {
        target[k] = source[k];
      }
    } else target[k] = source[k];
  }
}
const tgt = {};
copyExpand(tgt, src);
console.log(tgt);
```